# `cryptsetup reencrypt` seems to cripple digest iteration count

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I had a LUKS partition for which `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mydisk` gave (excerpt)

```
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 176646
    Salt:       xx xx ...
    ...
```

Running `cryptsetup reencrypt /dev/mydisk` while the container was offline removed the previous digest after it was done (understandably), leaving the following (`Iterations` has now changed to a much smaller value)

```
Digests:
  1: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 1000
    Salt:       xx xx ...
    ...
```

I doubt I selected the first iteration count manually, so I assume it was chosen by benchmark at `luksFormat` time. After the `reencrypt` the iteration count is much smaller, and to my poor knowledge so small that it is not recommended.

I would have understood if `reencrypt` re-chose a default, but clearly it didn't even run a benchmark. Since the digest protects the master key, is this a bug in `cryptsetup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `cryptsetup`. I've filed a report here: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/606.